# Can variable name be same as type name in vb.net in visual studio 2010?

Tags: vb.net

I am new to vb.net in visual studio 2010. I notice in the existing project, it has a sub defined as follows:

```
Public Sub SelectItem(ByVal **TabPage** As TabPage)
    For Each T As TabPage In TabPages
        T.IsSelected = False
    Next
    If **TabPage**  IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each t As TabPage In TabPages
            If m_TabsDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight Then t.SendToBack() Else t.BringToFront()
        Next
    End If
    End sub
```

If I understand right, the TabPage surrounded by ** is a variable and the regular Tabpage is a type. But is it legal to define variable in this way? I think in c/c++, it is illegal to define something like int int.

Even if it is legal, is it common that people define variables in this way in vb.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's legal and I've seen it on more than one occasion.

I think it's probably more common in VB.NET than C#, since C# it would normally be `tabPage` since it's case sensitive.

As a best practice I don't do it because it can cause confusion when reading the code.  It's easy to figure out that you're passing around an instance of an object, but using `currentTab` is also easy to understand.

So, Legal: Yes

Advisable: No

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you compile your code and see if it legal or not ?
it's legal, I think

Comment: It can compile, so it is legal then.